# Why is my Laravel date column displaying a time as well?

Tags: laravel

I am developing a prototype in Laravel 9 which currently contains 7 user tables. Several of those tables contain dates and all of them are defined as Laravel dates; they are all defined as MySQL dates in the database as well. I can't figure out why ***one*** of those date columns displays all its dates as a regular date, followed by a blank and then a time - 00:00:00 - whenever displayed in my blade templates. All of the other date columns display as a date (YYYY-MM-DD) without a time.

I am NOT requesting that a time (which is always 00:00:00/midnight) be shown in that column. Why is Laravel doing this and how can I make it stop?

I realize that I can suppress the time by appending `->format('Y-m-d')` but I shouldn't have to do that in the first place; if I only store a date rather that a DateTime or Timestamp, there should only be a date in the column and no need to suppress the time to keep it from displaying.

---

### UPDATE

Here is the migration for the table that is giving me trouble:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('non_driving_weekdays', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->date('non_driving_weekday_date');
            $table->string('reason', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->primary('non_driving_weekday_date', 'non_driving_weekday_date_PK');
            $table->foreign('reason', 'reason_FK')->references('reason_for_not_driving')->on('non_driving_reasons')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('restrict');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('non_driving_weekdays');
    }
};
```

Here is the blade that displays the index:

```xml
<x-layout>
    <div class="bg-gradient-to-b from-red-500 to-purple-100">
        <h1 class="text-3xl text-center text-white font-bold bg-indigo-700">Non-driving Weekdays - Index</h1>
        <h1 class="pb-5"></h1><!-- spacer beneath title -->
    
        @if (session()->has('message'))
        <div id="message"  
            x-data="{show: true}" 
            x-init="setTimeout(() => show = false, 5000)" 
            x-show="show"  
            class="w-1/3 mx-auto text-center text-black bg-yellow-300 rounded-md">
            <p class="text-xl py-1">{{session('message')}}</p>
        </div>
        @endif
    
        <div class="flex justify-center h-screen" style="display: grid; grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto; row-gap: 10px; padding: 10px">
    
            <table><tr><td><a href="/nonDrivingWeekdays/create"><img src="{{asset('icons/green-plus-circle-outline.svg')}}" width="50" alt="add icon"></a></td><td class="font-bold"><a href="/nonDrivingReasons/create">Add a new date where the drivers didn't drive</a></td></tr></table>
    
            {{-- If there are no non-driving weekdays, indicate that to the user.  --}} 
            @if (count($nonDrivingWeekdays) == 0)
                <p>No non-driving weekdays found.</p>
            @else
            
            {{-- If there are non-driving weekdays, display them.  --}}
            <div>
                <table class="border-black border-2 bg-white">
                <thead class="border-black border-2 text-white bg-gray-800">
                    <tr class="content-center">
                        <th class="border-black border-2 p-2 text-left">Date</th>
                        <th class="border-black border-2 p-2 text-left">Reason</th>
                        <th class="border-black border-2 p-2">View</th>
                        <th class="border-black border-2 p-2">Edit</th>
                        <th class="border-black border-2 p-2">Delete</th></tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody class="border-black border-2">
                    @foreach($nonDrivingWeekdays as $nonDrivingWeekday)
                    <tr class="border-black border-2">
                        {{-- ->format('Y-m-d') --}}
                        <td class="border-black border-2 p-2">{{$nonDrivingWeekday->non_driving_weekday_date}}</td> 
                        <td class="border-black border-2 p-2">{{$nonDrivingWeekday->reason}}</td>
                        <td class="border-black border-2 p-2 text-center"><a href="/nonDrivingWeekdays/show/{{$nonDrivingWeekday->non_driving_weekday_date}}"><img src="{{asset('icons/magenta-details.svg')}}" width="25" alt="view icon"></a></td>
                        <td class="border-black border-2 p-2 text-center"><a href="/nonDrivingWeekdays/edit/{{$nonDrivingWeekday->non_driving_weekday_date}}"><img src="{{asset('icons/yellow-lead-pencil.svg')}}" width="25" alt="update icon"></a></td>
                        <td class="border-black border-2 p-2 text-center">
                            <form method="POST" action="/nonDrivingWeekdays/destroy/{{$nonDrivingWeekday->non_driving_weekday_date}}">
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button><img src="{{asset('icons/red-delete.svg')}}" width="25" alt="delete icon"></button>
                            </form></td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            @endif
            <div>
                <p class="mt-6 p-4">{{$nonDrivingWeekdays->links()}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-layout>
```

This is the blade for the show() method:

```xml
<x-layout>
    {{-- <x-card class="p-10"> --}}
    <div class="bg-gradient-to-b from-purple-500 to-purple-100 h-screen"> 
        <h1 class="text-3xl text-center text-white font-bold bg-indigo-700">Non-driving Weekdays - Show One Weekday</h1>
        <h1 class="pb-5"></h1><!-- spacer beneath title -->
        <form method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="w-4/5 mx-auto">
            <div class="mb-6">
                <label for="non_driving_weekday_date" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">Reason</label>
                <input type="text" disabled class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="non_driving_weekday_date" value="{{$nonDrivingWeekday->non_driving_weekday_date}}"/>
            </div> 
            <div class="mb-6">
                    <label for="reason" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">Reason</label>
                    <input type="text" disabled class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="reason" value="{{$nonDrivingWeekday->reason}}"/>
                </div> 
                    
                <div class="mb-6">
                    {{-- Cancel submission of the form --}}
                    <a href="/nonDrivingWeekdays/index"><button type="button" class="text-xl text-white bg-black rounded-md py-2 px-4 hover:bg-white hover:text-black hover:outline hover:outline-2 hover:outline-black">Cancel</button></a>
                </div>                               
            </form>
    {{-- </x-card> --}}
    </div>
</x-layout>
```

And this is the blade template for the edit() method:

```xml
<x-layout>
    {{-- <x-card xclass="p-10 max-w-lg mx-auto mt-24"> --}}
    <div class="bg-gradient-to-b from-yellow-500 to-yellow-100 h-screen">
        <h1 class="text-3xl text-center text-white font-bold bg-indigo-700">Non-driving Weekdays - Edit One Weekday</h1>
        <h1 class="pb-5"></h1><!-- spacer beneath title -->    
        <form method="POST" action="/nonDrivingWeekdays/update/{{$nonDrivingWeekday->non_driving_weekday_date}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="w-4/5 mx-auto">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
            <div class="mb-6">
                <label for="non_driving_weekday_date" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">Non-driving&nbsp;weekday&nbsp;date</label>
                <input type="text" class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="non_driving_weekday_date" value="{{$nonDrivingWeekday->non_driving_weekday_date}}"/>
                @error('non_driving_weekday_date')
                    <p class="text-red-500 font-bold text-m mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
                @enderror
            </div> 
            <div class="mb-6">
                <label for="reason" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">Reason</label>
                <select id="reason" name="reason" class="h-10">
                    @foreach($reasons as $reason)
                        @if($reason->reason_for_not_driving === $nonDrivingWeekday->reason)
                            <option selected class="mx-10" value="{{$reason->reason_for_not_driving}}">{{$reason->reason_for_not_driving}}</option>
                        @else
                            <option class="mx-10" value="{{$reason->reason_for_not_driving}}">{{$reason->reason_for_not_driving}}</option>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
                
            <div class="mb-6">
                {{-- Submit the completed form --}}
                <button class="text-xl text-white bg-orange-500 rounded-md py-2 px-4 hover:bg-white hover:text-orange-500 hover:outline hover:outline-2 hover:outline-orange-500">Submit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                {{-- Cancel submission of the form --}}
                <a href="/nonDrivingWeekdays/index"><button type="button" class="text-xl text-white bg-black rounded-md py-2 px-4 hover:bg-white hover:text-black hover:outline hover:outline-2 hover:outline-black">Cancel</button></a>
            </div>
                                
        </form>
    {{-- </x-card> --}}
    </div>
</x-layout>
```

Lastly, here is the model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class NonDrivingWeekdays extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['non_driving_weekday_date', 'reason'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'non_driving_weekday_date';
    protected $keyType = 'date';
    public $incrementing = 'false';
}
```

Comment: What column is it? How did you define it in your migration? And in the model?

Comment: Just curious, have you checked with `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` as to what the column definitions actually are?

Comment: @Dhruv Saxena - I looked at the table definition in PhpMyAdmin and confirmed that the problematic column is defined as date. Just now, I ran the SHOW CREATE TABLE command for my table and it confirms that the datatype of the column is date.

Comment: @matiaslauriti - I'm updating the question with my table migration and the three blade templates that use the column; the problematic column is non_driving_weekday_date.

Comment: Not sure that this explains your current problem, but `false` should not be a string: `public $incrementing = 'false';` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#primary-keys

Comment: @Don't Panic - Good catch! Unfortunately, fixing that made no difference to the problem of the dates being displayed with times.

Comment: You can try to use cast on that column, specifying the format you need

Comment: @StewieSWS - eliminating the time after the fact isn't the problem; I can already do that by adding ->format('Y-m-d'). I'm trying to PREVENT the time from being displayed in the firist place. Do you have any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: Trying to understand, why `$casts = [ ... ];` is not an option? It will prevent time from being displayed.

Comment: @StewieSWS - I'm sure it would work fine but I'm trying to understand why the times are displaying in the first place. I assume I've coded something incorrectly and I'm trying to learn what I've done wrong so that I can do it right in the future.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Maybe input is type text while it should be date. if you want to know why in 1st case it's date, and in 2nd it's datetime, we need to see both codes to understand the difference.

Comment: @StewieSWS - What additional code do you want to see? My controller? My routes? What else?

Comment: @Henry made test with your code, it displays as date. So it should be somewhere else that it converts. If you dd this field in controller, is it datetime string or Carbon instance?

Comment: @StewieSWS - Problem solved! Unfortunately, I have to step out for a few hours now but when I return, I'll indicate how I solved the problem for the benefit of others. Your second last comment was instrumental in finding the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

StewieSWS gave me the clue that helped me solve this: I wasn't displaying the dates in form fields that were `<input type="date">`. Frankly, I'd forgotten there was a special input type for dates! In the blade for my index() method, I was displaying the data as a cell in a table and in the blades for the edit(), show() and create() methods, I was displaying them in `<input type="text">` fields.

As soon as I started displaying the dates in `<input type="date">` fields, they started displaying as normal dates WITHOUT any time component. I even got a little calendar icon at the right end of the box which lets me pick a date from calendar. As an added bonus, I even got some additional validating: when I tried to enter an impossible date, Feb 30, 2023, the input field detected it and displayed an appropriate message.

Comment: This is really the same as your initial workaround, using `->format('Y-m-d')`, isn't it? 
 Using a date input just means you are not displaying the time component, which is still there.  It does not explain why there is a time component in the first place, which was your (interesting!) question ...?

Comment: @Don't Panic - You are right: this only works around the problem but it doesn't explain why the time was being displayed in the first place. I'm just as mystified as before and I'm still curious to know why that happened. But I've got lots of other issues to settle so I'm going to let it go for now. Maybe someday someone will figure it out and add a comment to this question explaining why I was getting that behaviour.